# Moving codeigniter project to a new hosting provider - .htaccess and index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I just moved my functional codeigniter project to a new web hosting provider and am now having challenges removing the index.php from the URL using a standard .htaccess mod-rewrite.  Here is the .htaccess that was working fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479103/moving-codeigniter-project-to-amazon-ec2-htaccess-and-modrewrite-problems) discussion but I do not have root access to the apache server to make the suggested configuration change.

Using the provided .htaccess file above,

- Works fine:   http://www.mysite.com/index.php/plans
- Doesn't work:   http://www.mysite.com/plans

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Since obviously your question is unprecise please edit it and really explain what you actually want: What URL format should be usable by browsers? What internal URL structure is used by the server side application? Don't expect us to _guess_ what you want...

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to accept both forms of URLs likewise then you need two RewriteRules. Once accepting variants with then 'index.php' part and one without.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I do not need/want to accept the index.php in the URL so I really don't need the first RewriteRule.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question at all, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's not very clear, but a common problem with mod_rewrite rules like this is that some servers need the request to be passed as a query. I.e. you'd need to change your last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```